# Connection to the database fail after few hours from lift

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am developing an application on my localhost, and I am connecting to a remote database.
So when I stop working on the application over the night(sails still running), In the morning I always receive this error :
{
"code": "ECONNRESET",
"errno": "ECONNRESET",
"syscall": "read",
"fatal": true
}
and I have to restart sails, then everything work fine.
Any advice please?

Comment: PS: I have another localhost connection and this doesn't fail.